# Using Scripted field as time variable in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Kibana allows to conveniently [filter data or visualizations based on time](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/set-time-filter.html).
Apparently Kibana should automatically detect a "time variable" and use it for time-based filtering. In my specific case the field providing information about time is a Scripted Field: how can I specify that I want to use it for time-based filtering operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create `scripted fields` in the Kibana as mentioned in [this link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/scripted-fields.html#create-scripted-field).

Basically if you have index pattern, click on that index pattern and you should be able to view the below image. Note the `Add scripted field` section. I suggest you to explore it.

[image]

Once you do that, you should be able to see the scripted field name that you'd have created for that index in the visualiser and thereby you can make use of it as mentioned in the below image.

For e.g. I've created a field `myscript` as mentioned in above image and added `doc['date'].value` as script in it.

[image]

**Important Note:** You can only make use of this scripted date field as a `filter` option.

Kibana doesn't have an option to use this scripted field as the default date field or [`time filter field`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/set-time-filter.html) or as date field for [`TSVB`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/TSVB.html) as I suppose it requires the field to be indexed.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer. My question was exactly about the last point: using a scripted field as the default date field or time filter field, but sounds like you just can't do it... I was looking for a workaround

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: Kibana now supports using [Runtime Fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/runtime.html) in TSVB visualizations. They are available since 7.11 and are GA since 7.12.

Runtime fields will appear in TSVB just like any other field does (but might be slower to aggregate on).

[image]